# What does the solution guess for a PDE mean? - specific question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I got a partial differential equation, where a suggested solution is:

$J(W,t)=\dfrac{g(t)^{\gamma}W^{1-\gamma}}{1-\gamma}$

Everything but $g(t)^{\gamma}$ is known. $g(t)^{\gamma}$ is being introduced as a new function.

When i've searched on the internet, i've found that you introduce an arbitrary function when solving a PDE. 
Could $g(t)^{\gamma}$ in my case be the arbitrary function and what is the idea of doing it?

Comment: Remember constants of integration from Calc I? Since the derivative of a constant is zero, the antiderivative of a function is only determined up to an arbitrary additive constant. The partial derivative wrt $W$ of an arbitrary function of $t$ is similarly zero. In this way,arbitrary functions should be expected to pop up in general solutions to PDEs for basically the same reason arbitrary constants are introduced into general solutions to ODEs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The shape of $g(t)^{\gamma}$ is given by:
$(1-\gamma)J(1,t)$

Is that just a guess of the arbitrary function?